# How to add an hour to time?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, time

I am working with stored procedure while coding I feel some difficulties to add an hour to a time.I mean I have already a predefined time like 08:00 in my database and now I want to add 4 to this time and I want to get result as 12:00. How can I achieve it?? The way which I tried is below,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AttandenceEdit1](
@machid numeric(18,0),
)
AS
declare @time as time(0),@castedtime as time(0),
set @timein1=(select convert(time(0), from ShiftType where machId=@machid )// Value=08:00
print @time
set @addvalue =(DATEADD(HH,@timein1,4))
print @addvalue
```

I want the result 08:00+4=12:00
now it show error like **Argument data type time is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function**

Comment: DateAdd() function has the date as the last parameter and the number as the second parameter. ie. try switching your @timein1 with your 4 and see if that helps.

Comment: just do the cast for set @addvalue =(DATEADD(HH,CAST(@timein1 AS INT),4))

Comment: @mohan111,Explicit conversion from data type time to int is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the arguments to dateadd in the wrong order. This:

```
declare @time as time(0)
set @time='08:00'
print @time
declare @addvalue time(0)
set @addvalue =(DATEADD(HOUR, 4, @time))
print @addvalue
```

Will result in:

```
08:00:00
12:00:00
```

There are other issues with your stored proc code though that you need to fix (like undeclared variables, surplus comma, logic).

Answer (score 1):

Try by Changing the DATEADD() function syntax like this:

```
  set @addvalue =(DATEADD(HH,4,@timein1))
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bunch of issues in the code you've supplied, for example `@timein1` and `@addvalue` are not declared.

So here's a simple example:

```
DECLARE @time AS TIME = '08:00:00'

SELECT  @time AS OriginalTime,
        DATEADD(HOUR, 4, @time) TimePlus4Hours
```

Produces:

```
OriginalTime      |  TimePlus4Hours
====================================
08:00:00.0000000  | 12:00:00.0000000
```

Reference:

### [DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186819.aspx)

> Returns a specified date with the specified number interval (signed integer) added to a specified datepart of that date.
>
> DATEADD (datepart , number , date )